# How to add dropdown filter on jquery datatables plugin on single column?

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I want to add a drop-down filter on `dataTables`, only on a single column.
I have added the below code, but it add drop-downs on **all** columns:

```
$('#dataTables-example').DataTable({
    responsive: true,
    "pageLength": 100,
    "lengthMenu": [100, 250, 500, "All"],
    initComplete: function () {
        this.api().columns().every( function () {
        var column = this;
        $('#dataTables-example .head .head_hide').html('');

        var select = $('<select id="formfilter" class="filterdropdown"><option value="">'+$(column.header()).text()+'</option></select>')
            .appendTo( $(column.header()).empty())
            .on( 'change', function () {
                var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                    $(this).val()
                );
                column
                    .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                    .draw();
            });

        column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
            select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
        });
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Please take the time to format your code more carefully - the end result is so much easier to understand! Indent consistently, and never mix tabs and spaces.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

Change

```
this.api().columns().every( function () {
```

to

```
this.api().columns(1).every( function () {
```

where `1` is zero-based column index.

**NOTES**

- To add filter to certain columns use `columns([1,3])` format instead.
- You need to disable sorting for that column, because everytime the filter is clicked your column would be sorted. Otherwise use multi-line header or add filter to footer instead.

Comment: This should work. But what we can do, if the url changed and the table are reloaded. The filters still appears old data.
```$('#example').DataTable().ajax.url(newurl).load();```

Comment: @TheAlphaGhost, I assume in this case you would need to re-run the code in `initComplete` that generates filters.